# Restart a crashed screen

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen, inotifywait

I have a simple bash script, which uses the inotifywait command and based on the modification that is done, it run a rsync command. This is done in an infinite loop.

The script is run in a "screen" session, but unfortunately it crashes from time to time (no error as to why).

I've been searching for a way to "monitor" that specific screen/script and restart it when it crashes, but I'm struggling to find a solution to that.

The script is run "screen -AmdS script ./script.sh".

Script example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while inotifywait --exclude "(.log)" -r -e modify,create,delete /home/backups/
do
rsync -avz -e --update --rsh='ssh -pxxxxx' /home/backups/* user@target:/location/ --delete --force
done
```

So my question basically is, is there a way to monitor the 'screen' session and if it stops to start a new one or is there another way to keep this script running constantly and restart it (possibly not utilizing screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rerun your failing script in a loop until it succeeds. You can do this with

```sh
screen -AmdS script bash -c 'until ./script.sh; do echo "Crashed with exit code $?. Restaring."; sleep 1; done'
```

Every time your script fails, this will print that your script crashed and what exit code it had, pause for 1 second, and then rerun your script. As soon as your script succeeds (i.e., `./script.sh` terminates with a non-zero exit code), then the loop will terminate.

Note that if your script never succeeds, this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: attempt to be clearer

You could just issue

```
until ./script.sh ; do echo crashed ; sleep 1 ; done
```

in your terminal.  That will restart the script whenever it exits with non-zero result.

Comment: I'm relatively new to scripting. 

I've tried running the script as suggested, but I get:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

What I did was, create a new script and run that in screen (scriptception...):

#!/bin/bash
until ./script.sh
do
        echo "Script has crashed. Restarting"
        sleep 1
done

Comment: As @ShaneBishop says, sorry about that, hope you got it working

Comment: @ThomasStenhaug Please edit your answer to fix the syntax error. Answers should be standalone and not require a reader to refer to comments, especially since comments can be deleted.

Comment: @ShaneBishop Yes, that was unclear wording on my part.  I meant to say that I had attempted to fix my answer, based on your comment.